# kafka-run-class throwing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error

Tags: apache-kafka

I am running kafka_2.12-2.2.0 on Linux. When I run this command, it gives an OOM error. If I increase the memory options, it times out:

`./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092 --topic test` (gives OOM like `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`)

If I do this first `export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms1G"` then I get a timeout `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata`

My kafka server properties uses SSL, and I've read that there are sometimes issues with SSL. I notice there is no argument like `--command-config` that other commands have, so I don't know how this command would authenticate anyway.

How can I successfully run this command?