# How to get kafka offsets and the time when these offsets/records were created

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am basically trying to query offset info using `bin\kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell`
i am providing broker list and topic info as argument.
Ref -  [GetOffsetShell Utility](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-tools-GetOffsetShell.html)

But I am facing - `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Here are two SOF posts that touch base this same topic -
[Retrieve Timestamp based data from Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514167/retrieve-timestamp-based-data-from-kafka) and
[kafka-run-class throwing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59313030/kafka-run-class-throwing-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-error?noredirect=1&lq=1).
So this question is not about `kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell`. So i want to check what other tools are available to query kafka offset info - **information like offset and the time when the offset was created.**

`kafka-consumer-groups.sh` does not help my usecase as it does not provide/allow to get timestamp of when the record/offset was created.

Note: I suppose we are using confluent kafka - 5.3.x with SSL/JAAS auth mechnasim

Comment: and we are using Avro records

Comment: You are probably getting an error, first set the following to get the full error, export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms1G", secondly for sasl you'll need to set KAFKA_OPTS with jaas file and config file with truststore jks for ssl, post the full error for further ass8

Comment: You can use the kafka console consumer with property print.timestamp=true requesting specific offset adding max messages 1

Comment: @RanLupovich, i tried `print.timestamp=true` but not getting any timestamp. So do i assume that the broker is not defaulting to set one.

Comment: @RanLupovich basically, i want to consume records between a certain time window. if required i can post a new Q regarding this.

Comment: @RanLupovich, on another look - i see this - `"TimeStamp":"2021-06-09T06:18:13.251-0400"` is this the timestamp you are referring to. I am thinking this is set by the producer application as part of record data

Comment: The timestamp will be in unix epoch and need to be converted to human readable , it will be in the beginning of the printing of a record like a long number. When I need to filter for your type request usually I am using a free tool named jq which giving a lot of options working with jsons like filtering and selecting ...

Comment: "what other tools" -- Well, you could write your own JVM client that basically imports all the classes that `GetOffsetShell` does if you're not satisfied with the out-of-the-box arguments. Regarding your other comment - [consume between timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882882/how-to-consume-messages-between-two-timestamps-using-kafka-console-consumer)